# Unexpected bitmask result in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

There is strange situation in SQLite:

1st situation (normal) with bitmask 0x04:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("~/test.db")
cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT ((525824 & 04) == 04)")
print 'Sqlite bitwise masking 04: ', cursor.fetchall()      #sqlite bitmask
# Sqlite bitwise masking 04:  [(0,)] // E.g. false

print 'Python bitwise masking 04: ', 525824 & 0x04 == 0x04  #python bitmask
# Python bitwise masking 04:  False  // E.g. false
```

Same results in SQLite and Python. That's okay.

2nd situation (unexpected) with bitmask 0x00080000:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ((525824 & 00080000) == 00080000)")
print 'Sqlite bitwise masking 00080000: ', cursor.fetchall()
# Sqlite bitwise masking 00080000:  [(0,)] // E.g. False

print 'Python bitwise masking 00080000: ', 525824 & 0x00080000 == 0x00080000
# Python bitwise masking 00080000:  True  // E.g. True
```

Why results in 2nd case are different?

Comment: You're missing the `0x` prefix in the SQLite code.

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT (525824 & 0x00080000) == 0x00080000") isn't working. How can I fix it?

Comment: Got it. It simplier to use 524288 = int('0x00080000', 16) instead hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case works because a hex 4 is equal to a decimal 4. But, in the second case, a hexadecimal 0x80000 does not equal decimal 80000.